# Some conversion issues between the byte and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the I am trying:

```
import struct

#binary_data = open("your_binary_file.bin","rb").read()

#your binary data would show up as a big string like this one when you .read()
binary_data = '\x44\x69\x62\x65\x6e\x7a\x6f\x79\x6c\x70\x65\x72\x6f\x78\x69\x64\x20\x31\
x32\x30\x20\x43\x20\x30\x33\x2e\x30\x35\x2e\x31\x39\x39\x34\x20\x31\x34\x3a\x32\
x34\x3a\x33\x30'

def search(text):
    #convert the text to binary first
    s = ""
    for c in text:
        s+=struct.pack("b", ord(c))
    results = binary_data.find(s)
    if results == -1:
        print ("no results found")
    else:
        print ("the string [%s] is found at position %s in the binary data"%(text, results))


search("Dibenzoylperoxid")

search("03.05.1994")
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dec_new.py", line 22, in <module>
    search("Dibenzoylperoxid")
  File "dec_new.py", line 14, in search
    s+=struct.pack("b", ord(c))
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Kindly, let me know what I can do to make it functional properly.

I am using Python 3.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = ""
for c in text:
    s+=struct.pack("b", ord(c))
```

This won't work because `s` is a string, and `struct.pack` returns a bytes, and you can't add a string and a bytes.

One possible solution is to make `s` a bytes.

```
s = b""
```

... But it seems like a lot of work to convert a string to a bytes this way. Why not just use `encode()`?

```
def search(text):
    #convert the text to binary first
    s = text.encode()
    results = binary_data.find(s)
    #etc
```

---

Also, "your binary data would show up as a big string like this one when you .read()" is not, strictly speaking, true. The binary data won't show up as a big string, because it is a bytes, not a string. If you want to create a bytes literal that resembles what might be returned by `open("your_binary_file.bin","rb").read()`, use the bytes literal syntax `binary_data = b'\x44\x69<...etc...>\x33\x30'`

Comment: Wow.. silly me. It worked. thank you for your help.